# Jenkins Multi-Branch Project Plugin select two branches

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to use the Jenkins Multi-Branch Project Plugin to select just two Git branches to build consistently.  My branches are named `development` and `SIT`.  I cannot guarantee the names of any other branch.  In the downstream job created, I would like the branch name in the Git configuration to be:

`*/development` or `*/SIT`

so that the Github trigger can work.  There may be another configuration here that can make the Github trigger work, but this is the one I use for now.

I have tried:

`:(development|SIT)`, `(development|SIT)`, `development,SIT` `development|SIT`

all to no avail.

Comment: Try `(origin/development|origin/SIT)`